# Connection WebSocket with Session

Tags: python, websocket

good morning.
I'm trying to make an API for Quotex.com brokerage where your communication is done via websocket --> wss://ws.qxbroker.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
To connect to the broker I'm using Selenium. I can recover the session, but the difficulty is to send this data back to the websocket.

My code is this, where I try to connect and then send an order to broker.
Could someone help me please.

```
order = '42["orders/open",{"asset":"AUDCAD_otc","amount":6,"time":1637893200,"action":"put","isDemo":1,"requestId":1637892541,"optionType":1}]'

order2 = json.dumps(order)

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("""42["authorization",{"session":""" + session + ""","isDemo":1}]""")
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.send(order)
        ws.send(order2)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())
urlsocket = "wss://ws.qxbroker.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket"
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
            urlsocket, on_message=on_message,
            on_open=on_open)
            
ws.run_forever()
```

[Example of analysis via google chrome devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxIOt.png)

[Exemple Send Order for Broker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T8Lu.png)

Comment: Hey brother have you figured it out yet?